# Led strip light in threejs

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d, light

What could be the best way to simulate a led strip light in [threejs](https://threejs.org/docs/) like in the image? Is there any example around to make something similar?

[image]

Comment: One of approaches is to use lightmaps: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=lightm#webgl_materials_lightmap

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what kind of realism you want. There are always ways of making effects more realistic, but it quickly becomes rather complicated.

If we limit ourselves to THREE.js out-of-the-box functionality, though, we have the following light types at our disposal:

- AmbientLight
- DirectionalLight
- HemisphereLight
- PointLight
- RectAreaLight
- SpotLight

And out of these, I would personally recommend [RectAreaLight](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/RectAreaLight), because it represents an area light (the shape of which you can specify to match that of your led strip lights), which is a rectangle that emits light uniformly across its face. A lamp such as those in your picture do perhaps not emit light completely uniformly, but depending on what your goal is, it might be a close enough approximation. You may also combine several area lights to pursue certain effects.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved using an emissive material mesh with a RectAreaLight on top of it. Not sure about how to solve the missing of shadows, since RectAreaLight can't cast shadows

Comment: Interesting solution! Have you considered combining this with further lights such as Pointlights or DirectionalLight to obtain (an approximation) of shadows?